# DataContractSerializer misses an object

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, datacontractserializer

I am using DataContractSerializer to deserialize an xml into a List.

The xml structure is as follows:

```
<ArrayOfAttributes>
<Attributes>
<Type></Type>
<Value></Value>
<Name></Name>
</Attributes>
</ArrayOfAttributes>
```

The Attributes class has 3 string data members referenced through properties, they are:

```
[DataMember(Order=0)]
Type
[DataMember(Order=1)]
Value
[DataMember(Order=2)]
Name
```

When the WCF service returns more than one Attributes element in the XML, the Name object gets populated successfully but if only 1 Attributes element is returned, the value of Name remains null.

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: deleted my answer, as it no longer applies

Comment: Another thing I have observed is that if I remove the order tags, the Name doesn't get deserialized. Only Type and value turn up. Im using DataContractSerializer for type List<Attributes>.

Comment: Can you paste the code you are using to "deserialize the xml"?  What is unclear here is that you state you are using datacontract serializer to deserialze xml, but then you state that your issue is happening when WCF returns X number of attributes.  Are you manually using datacontractSerializer, or are you letting WCF do it for you?  More information please.

Answer (score 0):

Seems DataMember order is wrong as per pasted XML.

Try

[DataMember(Order=0)]
Type
[DataMember(Order=1)]
Name
[DataMember(Order=2)]
Value

Other option is

[DataMember]
Type
[DataMember]
Name
[DataMember]
Value

Try the second one, it will always work :)